# What snmp OID should I watch to see if my printers and switches is up an running

Tags: bash, networking, snmp

I am new to [snmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol), and I am trying to figure out what OID's I should get/trap to see if my printers, switches (and servers) is running? I do not need to know the details - just a simple test. I have successfully med get, getbulk, (and walk) request from a device, both from bash and [iReasoning MIB browser](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml).

*Edit:*

Maybe the

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
Name/OID: sysUpTime.0; Value (TimeTicks): 194 hours 43 seconds (69844352)
```

is used for just that!? What happens when something is wrong? -will this be reset immediately? -or will it just stop counting? or is it just the time since last power on?

Comment: What do you mean with up and running? You mean the online status? A server can be online but that doesn't necessary mean that it is running fine. If you just need the online status you can go for a ping or [nmap](http://nmap.org/). Otherwise I don't know if an OID exists. I mean there are some OIDs related to a particular hardware or process status but not a wide-variable, not that I remember.

Comment: @raz3r: I can see that the question is not simple for a _server_, so please ignore that part. By up and running, for a printer, I mean that it is online(can see that it answers snmp request), that it says ready in the diplay on the printer(or is currently printing), so there is no paper jam, or stalled jobs. For a switch: It is online, and there is no hang of the internal computer, or anything critically wrong(it is typically written to the log).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Printers

You should use the [Printer MIBv2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3805) to monitior printer error status for jams...

- `hrPrinterDetectedErrorState` reports printer errors such as low toner, jams, etc... the RFC contains details on what specific codes mean
- `hrDeviceStatus` will reveal the big picture ability of the printer to handle tasks.  For more info, see [Printer MIBv2, Section 2.2.13.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3805#section-2.2.13.2)

`sysUpTime.0` is an OID that reports the time a system's SNMP stack has been up (reference [RFC 1213: MIB-II](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1213)).  If this value is returned and incrementing, it's a 99% safe bet that a printer is up.  Most people use `sysUpTime` to detect whether the device has rebooted for some reason; if that happens, you'll see a sudden decrease in `sysUpTime.0`, unless your last value was around 248 days (where a 32-bit counter would roll).

### Ethernet Switches

Checking the basic health of ethernet switches is usually done with checks to `sysDescr.0` or `sysUpTime.0`; the problem with this heuristic comes if you care about the up/down status of particular links... at that point, you need to check values from `ifOperStatus`, which is indexed by `ifIndex` and uses interface names from `ifName`.  See the following examples...

```
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$ ## Walk ifName correlated to ifIndex
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c Public 172.25.116.6 .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.1 = STRING: "Fa0/0"
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.2 = STRING: "Nu0"
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$ ## Walk ifOperStatus (up==1)
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c Public 172.25.116.6 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.1 = INTEGER: 1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.2 = INTEGER: 1
[mpenning@Hotcoffee ~]$
```

Thus we know from the example that both interface "Fa0/0" (index: 1) and "Nu0" (index: 2) have an ifOperStatus of "up"; the index value is the last integer returned in the OID of the results.

### Scripting

I assume you will use `bash` for your monitoring scripts; if so, check out [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) for your SNMP manager

Comment: I want to create a http status page, that uses php to call a perl script, that uses bash commands. the perl script reads ip's from a file, and will send a few snmpget commands to test, if the device is running. Does all that sound ok to you? -or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: There are a lot of things that depend on the detailed requirements... if this is an internal corporate app, what you described sounds fine; however, you probably can do everything directly in PHP, if that's what you're most fluent in.  You should be able to make `snmpget` or `snmpwalk` calls directly from either PHP or Perl.  I encourage people to use the language they're most fluent in, unless it just can't do what you need